# First rails application: routes.rb not leading to right page(?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Apologies in advance if this is so basic I probbaly shouldn't post it here. I'm not even sure if the title actually describes the issue. I am just starting to look at Ruby on Rails, and am following this page to set up "my first application": http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Now, when I get to the point where I add

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

Into the routes.rb file and try and access it, it all goes wrong. First I thought it was a permissions issue, but I can access the views/layouts/welcome/index.html.erb file directly in the browser.

I'm so new to this that I haven't got far enough to know what I'm looking for in troubleshooting, hence this post.

When starting the rails server, I do get what looks like errors on restart and hangup signals, but I doubt this is the problem. Output listed here just in case.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Private Caller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Loading the root page gives the following server output:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-28 13:17:23 +0200
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (13.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3742ms



ActionView::Template::Error (TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method):
     5:
     6:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
     7:
     8:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     9:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    10:
    11:     </head>

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___750167210_57076860'
```

It kind of looks to me as though it does load the index page, but then something else triggers and it's redirected to a page that doesn't work. The content of the page it's directed to (views/layouts/application.html.erb) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blog</title>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    </head>

  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Content of routes.rb for reference is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  root 'welcome#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines in `/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Comment: Same error as above I'm afraid, only the server output displays the changed code (so I know it's picked it up, and besides, I did stop and start it just to make sure).

Comment: `'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload'` should work https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#reloading-when-assets-change

Comment: you will not get error in css but in the html file where you are including it

Comment: check the recent changes if you did any

Comment: if you comment or remove link `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`, then is it work?

Comment: Should I even be getting to this page? Why is it not directed to the index page as per the routes.rb file?

Comment: @urbanespaceman it redirect to index page but the layout application.html.erb is called

Comment: @urbanespaceman if you dont want layout then add `render layout: false` in controller action

Comment: If I comment both the lines in there (the stylesheet _link_tag and the javascript_include_tag) then it works!

Comment: great!! try to remove `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147813/discussion-between-puneet18-and-urbanespaceman).